# Facebook Dialog is opening and closes immediately

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am new there. Hope you are doing well. I have integrate Facebook login api in android. Unfortunately, When I click on "Login with Facebook" Button. The dialog box opens and closes immediately. It will not entering even in onSuccess method.

Here is my code. Please have a look on it. Plus I have set the status to live as well. But when I switched the status back to off and then click on again. I see this message, 
"Your app wont be able to access unapproved permissions or feature that required App review." Need your guidance please.
Thanks in advance

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: SignInActivity Call");

        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.loginWithFacebook);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday"));
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                System.out.println("Sucess"+loginResult);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code

                System.out.println("Exception"+exception);
            }
        });





    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

            if(currentAccessToken == null){
                Helper.toast(SigninActivity.this, "Null");
            }else{
                getProfileDetail(currentAccessToken);
            }

        }
    };

    public void getProfileDetail(AccessToken accessToken){

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                try {
                    String email = object.getString("email");
                    String name = object.getString("name");
                    String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                    String id = object.getString("id");

                    System.out.println("Data is there"+ email+name+birthday+id);

                    Helper.userBirthday = birthday;
                    Helper.userEmail = email;
                    Helper.userName = name;


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Error is"+e.getMessage().toString());

                }


            }
        });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }
```

Comment: Well. I got where the problem is. When I switched Status to development mode from Live, It permit me to login. However, When I switched to Live, it will not permit me to login and show this error.

Your app won't be able to access unapproved permissions or features that require App Review